# What's the difference or when should I apply ":" vs "=" in Python?

Tags: python, assignment-operator

I'm new at the site but I've been looking to know the difference of the applications of "`:`" and "`=`".

I know that "`=`" is an assignation operator, like `a= 12`, so like b= any DataFrame, c could be `c= b.copy()`... but I was looking the following code and didn't understand why instead of using "`=`" they use "`:`" to assign the values of the pandas columns. I know it follows a dictionary structure, but I read that for a dictionary the values can't be repeated when they're first created. So in this example of a df creation:

```py
n = 100 # Number of registrations
age = np.random.randint(18, 25, n)
gender = np.random.choice(['M', 'F'], n)
math_score = np.random.randint(0, 100, n)
english_score = np.random.randint(0, 100, n)
physics_score = np.random.randint(0, 100, n)
# Compute Average
average_score = (math_score + english_score + physics_score) / 3
# Create dataFrame
data = pd.DataFrame({
'Age': age,
'Gender': gender,
'Math Score': math_score,
'English Score': english_score,
'Physics Score': physics_score,
'Average Score': average_score
})
```

I can't fully understand the match between this structure and the stuff I read (HubSpot) that there should be unique values... if every value is given randomized is mostly probable than in 100 reps at least one value is the same. But I also feel familiar this dataFrame construction, with a dictionary like structure. However, how I'm relatively new to programmation it confuses me...

Anyways, my doubt is also because I was inspecting the kwargs of Seaborn Boxplot and I found that to customize median and mean visualization it's something like this (this is what I've done until now and works fine, but I don't feel comfortable making something work but not knowing what I did...):

```py
sns.boxplot(x="Age", data= df, orient ="h", color= "darkblue", medianprops={"color": "red"}, boxprops={"facecolor": (0, 0, 1, .7)},
            showmeans= True, meanprops={"marker": "o", "markerfacecolor": "black", "markeredgecolor": "black", "markersize": "6"})
```

Thanks in advance, I know it's pretty long and I'm plenty sure it could be wrote in fewer lines... working on that! =)

In both cases, when changing "`:`" to "`=`", like:

```py
data = pd.DataFrame({
'Age'= age,
'Gender'= gender,
'Math Score'= math_score,
'English Score'= english_score,
'Physics Score'= physics_score,
'Average Score'= average_score
})
```

It underlines "Age", "Gender", ..., "Average Score" telling:

for Age -> SyntaxError: cannot assign to literal here. Maybe you mean "`==`" instead of "`=`"?
for the "Gender" and the rest -> Expected parameter name

Comment: `=` is used for assigning variables or named function parameters, `:` is used for separating keys and values in a dictionary.

Comment: Note that you could do something like this, but only if your column names don't have whitespace: `data = pd.DataFrame(dict(age=age, gender=gender))`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`=` is used to assign a variable a value. `:` is used to separate a key from its value in a dictionary construction. The key is not a variable, so it doesn't use `=`. The key is an index in the dictionary. Variables and dictionary keys are similar but distinct concepts (in fact, you can obtain a dictionary containing your variables, but I don't want to confuse you).

A dictionary key is what you pass, as a *string*, to `[]` to get its value. For example, if you have a dictionary:

```py
d = { 'Age': 33, 'Gender': 'male' }
```

you would print the age with `print(d['Age'])`. (Here `d` is a variable that holds a dictionary.) If `Age` were a variable, you'd have:

```py
Age = 33
```

and print it with `print(Age)`. Note that variables are not in quotes and dictionary key literals are. But this allows you to do this:

```py
key='Age'
print(d[key])
```

Output:

```
33
```

This doesn't work for a variable*. This allows you to do access values programmatically like

```py
dict_list = [ f'{k}: {v}' for k,v in d.items()]
print('\n'.join(dict_list))
```

The output of this is:

```
Age: 33
Gender: male
```

* I'm simplifying things for newbies. There are ways to do this but we're glossing over these as advanced, often inadvisable topics.

Answer (score 2):

You are entirely correct that it is a dictionary that is passed to the `pd.DataFrame`constructor to make your Dataframe. However, it is not correct that a dictionary cannot have repeated values. It only cannot have repeated keys. So this is completely allowed

```py
{
    "a": 1,
    "b": 1,
}
```

where both the key "a" and "b" correspond to the value 1.
However this:

```py
{
    "a": 1,
    "a": 2,
}
```

will not work. Or, it will, but it will just override the first one, giving this dictionary:

```py
{
    "a": 2,
}
```

The reason we can have the same value many times but not the same keys, is because we only index into the dictionary in one direction. So we only take `dct[key]` to retrieve a corresponding value, which wouldn't make sense if it gave us multiple. But it's entirely possible that multiple people for instance have the same age, so multiple values are not an issue.

Hope this helps :)